# Selecting a certain row from a dataset

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, xpath

I have a Dataset and want to display the containing rows in a WPF-Contorl. The problem is, that the control is sort of a circuit diagram. Thus I created a template to show the values and placed multiple instances of it in my circuit control. Currently the XAML-code in the circuit looks like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=.[0]}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValueTpl}" />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=.[1]}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValueTpl}" />
```

And so on. So I'm able to show the n-th row at a specified position. The problem is, that I can't expect the right order anymore and I would rather need something like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=.[id=5]}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValueTpl}" />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=.[id=8]}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValueTpl}" />
```

I read that XPath ought to be supported, but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported if you type `XPath` instead of `Path`...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I need to use `XPath`, but there's more to it.
My mistakes were:
You can't use a `DataSet` directly but need to wrap it in a `XmlDataDocument`
Also my problem involved the namespaces. To surpress them you have to set `DataSet.Namespace = String.Empty` prior to creating the `XmlDataDocument`.
If you want to use Namespaces you have to create a `XmlNamespaceMappingCollection` in XAML like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection x:Key="namespace">
        <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="ds" Uri="http://tempuri.org/DataSet.xsd" />
    </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In order to reference the namespace in the XPath. Simply adding it as xmlns won't work (as opposed to what I expected).
Then referencing a certain row worked like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding XPath='//TableName[4]'}" />
```

If you use namespaces, you need to reference the `XmlNamespaceManager`

```
<Label Content="{Binding XPath='//ds:TableName[4]'}" Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource namespace}" />
```

Now while this very simple XPath works, adding a constraint will lead to full CPU usage and my program not continuing:

```
<Label Content="{Binding XPath='//TableName[Process = 4]'}" />
or
<Label Content="{Binding XPath='//ds:TableName[ds:Process = 4]'}" Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource namespace}" />
```

**EDIT**
It seems like the binding must be in `OneTime` Mode. Simply changing it to

```
<Label Content="{Binding Mode=OneTime, XPath='//TableName[Process = 4]'}" />
```

made it work. I also use a `ContentTemplate` and in the template the binding might be `TwoWay`, but there the XPath is primitive (e.g. `./Prozess`) , maybe thats why.

Comment: Ok, it stops crashing, if i set `Mode` to `OneTime`,
Though this is not what I need...